# Quartz Trigger not firing third time onwards. How to reapeat it forever?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Cron trigger in Quartz is getting fired for the first and second time but won't fire third time onwards. What could be the reason for it? What should I do to repeat it forever?
I've tried these two possibilities:-

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity("DBCheckTrigger", "DBCheckGroup")
                   .StartNow()
                   .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(60).RepeatForever())
                   .Build();
```

and

```
string cronexp = " 0 0/1 * * * ? ";
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity("DBCheckTrigger", "DBCheckGroup")
                   .WithCronSchedule(cronexp)
                   .WithPriority(1)
                   .Build();
await schedulerDB.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Can anybody please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: I can not understand your question. Do you want to call the job every 3 minutes?

Comment: @PWND i've edited my question. I'm trigerring every 1 min. Whatever I do, it won't trigger after first two times.

Comment: Not sure about Quartz cron expression and if they do something special, but if you want it to trigger every minute, shouldn't the cron expression be `*/1 * * * *`?

Comment: @JLe Doesn't matter if I use any Cron expression or Interval in seconds, Non firing trigger condition exits persistently.